# Running Consul on Rancher

Tags: consul, rancher

I am trying to get Consul to run on Rancher.
This seems like it should be an easy thing to do as there is already a catalog item for it.

We have however failed to get that to work, it throws an exception upon start up saying that the json in server.json is invalid. (where this server.json is located or what it is used for is a mystery to us still)

So, I've tried to get it up and running manually.
There are a few docker-compose scripts out there, none of which work in rancher.

I've tried to set up each server manually, still failing, each node complains that it does not get any ping from the other nodes.

[image]

Here is the docker-compose file that I am trying to construct:
https://github.com/AsynkronIT/ConsulCluster/blob/master/docker-compose.yml

```
consul1:
  ports:
  - 8400:8400/tcp
  - 8500:8500/tcp
  - 8600:8600/tcp
  - 8301:8301/tcp
  - 8301:8301/udp
  - 8302:8302/tcp
  - 8302:8302/udp
  environment:
    CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG: '{"skip_leave_on_interrupt": true}'
  labels:
    io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
  tty: true
  command:
  - agent
  - -server
  - -bootstrap-expect=3
  - -ui
  hostname: consulserver1
  image: consul:latest
  stdin_open: true

consul2:
  ports:
  - 8400:8400/tcp
  - 8500:8500/tcp
  - 8600:8600/tcp
  - 8301:8301/tcp
  - 8301:8301/udp
  - 8302:8302/tcp
  - 8302:8302/udp
  environment:
    CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG: '{"skip_leave_on_interrupt": true}'
  labels:
    io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
  tty: true
  command:
  - agent
  - -server
  - -bootstrap-expect=3
  - -retry-join=consul1
  hostname: consulserver2
  image: consul:latest
  stdin_open: true
  links:
  - consul1

consul3:
  ports:
  - 8400:8400/tcp
  - 8500:8500/tcp
  - 8600:8600/tcp
  - 8301:8301/tcp
  - 8301:8301/udp
  - 8302:8302/tcp
  - 8302:8302/udp
  environment:
    CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG: '{"skip_leave_on_interrupt": true}'
  labels:
    io.rancher.container.pull_image: always
  tty: true
  command:
  - agent
  - -server
  - -bootstrap-expect=3
  - -retry-join=consul1
  hostname: consulserver3
  image: consul:latest
  stdin_open: true
  links:
  - consul1
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Is there anyone else that have actually managed to get consul to work with Rancher?

This bit looks super strange to me:

```
memberlist: Suspect consulserver1 has failed, no acks received
memberlist: Got ping for unexpected node 'consulserver1' from=172.17.0.3:8301
memberlist: Got ping for unexpected node consulserver1 from=172.17.0.3:47164
memberlist: Failed TCP fallback ping: EOF
memberlist: Marking consulserver1 as failed, suspect timeout reached (0 peer confirmations)
```

The log says it hasnt got any acks from consulserver1, and at the same time it complains about unexpected node consulserver1 is pinging it.. WHY?

Comment: also, if I ssh into the containers, I can manually do "consul join consul1" and the connection will be OK for a few sec, all members have status OK, then all the others fail again..

Comment: Like you, I had a few problems getting a Consul stack running. Even the catalog options wouldn't work for me.

I was finally able to get it working using:

CONSUL_BIND_INTERFACE: eth0

and setting the host to 'net'

I'm not satisfied with my stack yet, but it is up and running and in use. When I revisit the stack later on I would like to make it work with rancher internal networking.